# Change minimum password length with restful_authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, restful-authentication

Is there a way to change the minimum length for passwords with restful_authentication? Currently it's 6 characters and I need another value.

I've tried calling validates_length_of before and after Authentication::ByPassword like this

```
validates_length_of :password, :within => 4..40, :if => :password_required?  
include Authentication::ByPassword
```

and like this:

```
include Authentication::ByPassword
validates_length_of :password, :within => 4..40, :if => :password_required?
```

but the minimum password remained at 6.

Answer (score 0):

go to vendor/plugins/restful-authentication/lib/authentication/by_password.rb and edit this string

```
validates_length_of :password, :within => 6..40, :if => :password_required?
```

Comment: And then the plug in is updated and the web app breaks for no apparent reason.

Comment: what exactly did you write? 'cause I've just try it and it's work perfect

Comment: What I've tried is on the question. Not sure what you mean beyond that. My point is that if you modify third party code without submitting upstream and/or creating a branch and using it, then you risk updating that code and losing your modifications, and that can be very hard to track and debug.

Comment: it's not big and critic patch, although restful_authentication is quite old and I don't think it is supporting well and till updating plugin

Answer (score 0):

[ActsAsAuthentic](http://github.com/gundestrup/acts_as_authenticated) has configuration options like so:

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.merge_validates_length_of_password_field_options       :within => 4..40
  config.merge_validates_confirmation_of_password_field_options :within => 4..40
end
```

Unfortunately, RestfulAuthentication doesn't have these configuration options. The *right* solution would be to fork the [RestfulAuthentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) project and add them.

In the mean time, you could monkey-patch `Authentication::ByPassword.included`:

```
# in app/models/user.rb:
Authentication::ByPassword.class_eval do
  def self.included(base)
    recipient.extend(ModelClassMethods)
    recipient.class_eval do
      include ModelInstanceMethods

      # Virtual attribute for the unencrypted password
      attr_accessor :password
      validates_presence_of :password, :if => :password_required?
      validates_presence_of :password_confirmation, :if => :password_required?
      validates_confirmation_of :password, :if => :password_required?
      validates_length_of :password, :within => 4..40, :if => :password_required?
      before_save :encrypt_password
    end
  end
end
```